# I can't authenticate using 'elastic' , 'kibana_system' in ELK version 8.5

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ELK cluster consists of **three** nodes. I can't access Kibana using its URL https://kibana_IP:5601.

When I checked the logs of **/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log** I found these errors:

`Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]`

When I checked the logs of kibana, I found the below error:

`Unable to authenticate user [kibana_system] for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]`

I tried to reset the password for elastic user using this command **/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -i -u elastic**

but I got this error:

`Error: Failed to determine the health of the cluster. Cluster health is currently RED`

When I try using this command
`curl --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt -XGET "https://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v" -u elastic`

I am getting the below error:
`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/_cat/indices?v]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/_cat/indices?v]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}`

I checked elastisearch service in all nodes and it is up and running.

How to solve this problem, please?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like at least one of the indexes is RED.

**1- find the RED index**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v" -u elastic:password
```

can be `HTTP` try with `HTTPS`

**2- delete the RED index (if you can)**

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/index_name" -u elastic:password
```

Note: do not delete the system indices which start with `.` for example `.security`

**3- check the cluster health again**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200" -u elastic:password
```

---

More:

to understand the reason of RED cluster status you can elasticsearch.log
If you have snapshot you can restore the indices from the latest snapshot

Comment: I updated the main topic with the output of the first command, please.

Comment: Hmm, elasticsearch needs to authenticate **elastic** user with `.security` index but it looks like the index is corrupted.

Comment: I recommend disabling security and restarting the elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: Set `xpack.security.enabled: false` in elasticsearch.yml, restart elasticsearch, and try again the above commands.

Comment: after disabling `xpack.security.enabled: false`  then I can list the indexes without password. All indexes are **Yellow**.

Comment: Kindly I need your support to start the cluster using `xpack.security.enabled: true`

Comment: Oh, nice to hear the cluster is yellow now. Just set back to `true` again and restart the cluster and run `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-passwords.html

Comment: After setup the elastic password you can need to reset the `kibana_system` password.
`bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u kibana_system --interactive`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reset-password.html

Comment: Are these command should be running in all cluster nodes or only one node.
`bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive`

`bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u kibana_system --interactive`

Comment: I updated the password for `elastic` and `kibana_system` using `bin/elasticsearch-reset-password` and I updated `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml` with the new password for `kibana_system` but when I start kibana, I am getting the below error:

`ERROR: Action failed with '[]incomatiable_cluster_routing_allocation]' Incompatible Elasticsearch cluster settings detected. Remove the persistent and transient Elasticsearch cluster setting 'cluster.routing.allocation.enable' or set it to a value 'all' to allow migration to proceed.`

Comment: I used the below command to enable shard allocation and it is working fine now.

`curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.enable": null
  }
}

'`